# Javascript: how to turn off debugger permanently?

Tags: javascript, vscode-debugger

I am a hobbyist, writing some simple js codes in VSCODE on a MAC, with Chrome Dev Tools. I do not have any debug extensions installed. I have used the debugger in  the past without any luck.
My running procedure is as follows: Open with live server > Right click and select "Inspect" > Select "Console".
If for instance I get a Reference Error, I click "Reload" and up comes the "Paused in Debugger" box with 2 options, "Resume Script Execution" and "Step over next function call".  How do I turn off the debugger permanently?  I have removed all breakpoints which crept in with the previous file, but cannot think of any other options. Also I find most of the web resources for debugging are over my head. Can anyone recommend a good debug site for a beginner?  Thanks.